# can't open php in mozila

Tags: php

So I have all the packs and everything else. I can open http://localhost/info.php and I am using atom as editor. But if I make code like hello and save it as hello.php mozila dosen't open it. How can I save files with .php and still open them.

Comment: you have apache installed?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install apache on your machine by using following command

sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils

It will install apache as well as its documentation and utilities

Comment: its instaled, I saved it, and it dosen't let me to save files to var/www directory. And if I trie to open php file it ask me if I whant so save it or open it with some kind of program

Comment: First go to your file system and press ctrl+L, it will show you a search box, type 'sftp://localhost' and press enter, it will ask for authentication, after that I hope you can copy your file in /var/www.

Comment: It says that I don't have permition to do something.